# Properties and applications of complex logarithms and exponentials.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, exponentiation

We have these two identities where $a>0$ real, $n$ integer and $z$ complex :
\begin{align}
(a^z)^n=a^{nz} \tag{1} \\
(a^n)^z=a^{nz} \tag{2}
\end{align}

> $(1)$ is true. Is $(2)$ also true?

Assuming that $(2)$ is true, consider for $a,b>0$ real, $n,m$ integer and $z_1,z_2$ complex, and the steps below must be in this order:

\begin{align}
& a^n = b^m \\
& (a^n)^{z_1} = (b^m)^{z_2}\\
& a^{nz_1} = a^{mz_2} \tag{3}
\end{align}

> What will happen if we take the natural $\log$ of the last equation above? Since $z_1, z_2$ are complex, the properties of $\log$ are now different.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I saw in this [post][1] the following formula, for some integer $k$:
\begin{align}
\log_{b_1}({a_1}^d) = \dfrac{d \ln(a_1) + 2 \pi i k}{\ln(b_1)}
\end{align}

and tried to apply on $(3)$ considering $b_1=e$, the natural $\log$:

\begin{align}
&a^{nz_1} = b^{mz_2}\\
&\ln a^{nz_1} = \ln b^{mz_2} \\
& nz_1 \ln a + 2i \pi k=  mz_2 \ln b. \tag{4}
\end{align}

But I got some weird results working with the above, so something is wrong. I highlighted the questions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that my answer is complicated, but that is because the subject is complicated and even seemingly innocuous expressions like $1^z$ are actually complicated since while we generally and implicitly *take* $1^z=1$, so constant, it is legitimate to take $1^z=\exp({2\pi iz})$ too and the last is a completely different object, an entire integral function.

So coming to your question about 4:

Line 1: $a^{nz_1}=b^{mz_2}$ - I do not know what each side means for you, since I do not know what you mean by $a^{nz}$ - see above even for $a=1$; if it means the canonical interpretation, $a^{nz}=exp(n\log a z)$, where $exp, \log$ are given *unambiguously* by the power series mentioned in my answer, the line is correct; also the line can be correct in other circumstances, but it can also be incorrect with differe3nt choices for each side

Line 2: Only as sets in general so the set {$\ln (a^{nz_1}$} equal to the set {$\ln b^{mz_2}$}, not necessarily as individual values

Line 3: same as line 2, as sets only not as individual values, so RHS should be understood as a set too

Comment: I should have said earlier but $a,b,z_1,z_2$ are constants and $m,n>0$ are integer variables. I will be more specific.$ a,b>1 $ are real constants. $n, m>0$ are integers variables. $z_1, z_2$ are complex constants not functions like $e^z$. For example:$ a=3, b=e, z_1=i, z_2=1+i$, and $m,n$ are positive integers variables. So $a^{z_1n}=b^{z_2m}$ means $3^{in}=e^{(1+i)m}$. Using the formula to take the natural $\log$ of the last equation, we have: $in\ln 3+2i\pi k= (1+i)m$ for some integer $k$ (or for all integer $k$?). Is this now true? Did this comment help at all?

Comment: Where did you get $3^{in}=e^{(1+i)m}$? LHS has absolute value $1$, RHS has absolute value $e^m$, so the relation cannot be true except for $m=0$ which forces $n=0$

Comment: So the solution to the equation is $m=n=0$. I'm interested in solving equations like that one. I didn't thought about taking the absolute value, since I was so focused in taking the $\log$ because that's what we usually do to solve exponential equations. But since it seems so difficult to take the $\log$ when we have imaginary units in the expoent i wasn't able to solve those kind of equations. So, the best route to solve $3^{in} = e^{(1+i)m}$ or similar equations is to take the absolute value rather than taking the $\log$?

Comment: First is absolute value since that is easy (also for exponentials of positive reals it is just $a^{\Re{z}}$, so in particular purely imaginary powers of positive reals have absolute value $1$ and that you can see immediately after a few exercises); then logarithm since there the multivalued nature comes into play and makes it trickier, but again a few exercises and you start getting a feel at least in the setting above

Comment: I put the equation on wolfram and took a screenshot and its on the post now. In there it's take the $\log$, and solves for $n$. Thats whats I wanted to learn, how to take the $log$ and solve for a variable.

Comment: $n$ is not real in the wolfram screenshot unless $m=0$; otherwise it's correct - I thought you wanted integral or real solutions, but here $n$ belongs to a family of complex non-real ( except for 0) numbers indexed by integral $k$, so maybe there is the confusion; the original post asked about integral $n$

Comment: and actually, the solutions can be written even more explicitly as: $n= \frac{m(1-i)+2\pi k}{\log 3}$, where $k$ is integral and it holds for arbitrary complex $m$, with solutions that are generally non-real, so not integral which I thoughht was the point of the question; if you just want to solve exponential equations in arbitray complex number, that's not that hard as the exponential map is $\infty$ to $1$ from the plane to the punctured plane at the origina, so there will always be infinite solutions unless you need to get zero when there are none...

Comment: Since $n=\frac{m(1-i)+2k\pi}{\ln 3}$ for integer solutions that would imply in $m=0$ for $i$ to vanish and $k=0$. So $m=n=0$. Which was achieved without taking the absolute values but taking the $\log$ which gives a more general answer. Wolfram said "take the $\log_3$ on both sides" (let's pretend it used the $\ln$) it used the formula: $\ln a^{zn}=nz\ln a+2i\pi k$? To solve this equation, the formula worked, but maybe are cases when it doesn't? The formula always holds or are conditions where it works or doens't? Sorry for asking so much. But I really appreciate you taking the time to answer.

Comment: First note that $\log_{3}x=\frac{1}{\log 3}\log x$ so it doesn't matter that you take base $3$ or natural (see denominator); as long as $a>0$, we tend to define $a^z = \exp(z\log a)$, where $\log a$ is the real one given by the power series I mentioned (or if you want the usual real logarithm from the theory of real functions), so say $3^i=\Sigma{\frac{(i \log 3)^n}{n!}} , 1^i=1$ etc; however in general $3^i$ can be something else too since we can use a different logarithm of $3$ to define it, so the formula works with this caveat, that we know what we talk about, when we talk about $a^z$

Comment: Wolfram by default uses the standard branch of the logarithm for positive numbers, so that's why you got what is in the screenshot and it may be what the problem you wanted to solve required, but in general I cannot emphasize how important is to understand what we mean when we talk about a complex power even of a positive number, and even of $1$, since $1^z$ may or may not be $1$ depending on context

Answer (score 1):

For 1, you actually need $a \neq 0$ since for $a=0, a^z$ doesn't really make sense unless $z$ is a positive integer (just think how you would make sense of $0^{-1}$),

For $a>0$ there is a canonical choice of $\log a$ (the unique one that's real and for example given by $\log 1 =0$, $\log a = -\Sigma{\frac{b^n}{n}}, b=1-a, 0<a<1$, $\log a = -\log \frac{1}{a}, a>1$), so both sides are $\exp(nz\log a)$, where $\exp{z} = \Sigma{\frac{z^n}{n!}}$ is the standard entire exponential function.

For $a<0$ it gets tricky since there is no canonical choice of $\log a$, so you need to fix one such (e.g. $\log a = \log|a| + \pi i$) and then both sides are $\exp(nz\log |a| + n\pi i z)$

For 2, same thing, for $a>0$ with the canonical choices of $\log a, \log {a^n} =n\log a$ as above, both sides are $\exp(nz\log a)$, while for $a=0$ either expression doesn't generally make sense and for $a<0$, if you fix a choice as above and **use it consistently in the sense that** $\log {a^n}$ is the pointwise choice $n\log a$, so for example $\log {(-1)^2}= 2\pi i$, not the canonical choice $0$, both sides are still $\exp(nz\log |a| + n\pi i z)$

**Note that in both 1 and 2 you need to fix the same $\log a$ for $a<0$ on both sides as otherwise the expressions won't generally be equal unless $z$ is an integer too, while in addition in 2, you need to use the choice consistently as noted above; for $a>0$ we have that by "default"**

Since $\exp$ is periodic the expressions in 1 and 2 are well defined and unique (up to the choice of $\log a, a <0$ and consistency of its use as noted) so you can say that both 1 and 2 are true if interpreted appropriately. Taking logarithms though is very tricky, since being the inverse of periodic $\exp$, $\log$ is multivalued, so expression involving logarithms tend to be equal only set-wise, not pointwise - e.g $(-1)^2=1$ means $exp(2\pi i) = \exp (0)$, perfectly legitimate as both sides are $1$; taking logarithms it just means that the set {$2\pi i + 2k\pi i$} is equal to the set {$2k\pi i$} which again is perfectly legitimate but doesn't tell you anything about individual values; so, in particular, it is very easy to get incorrect expressions taking logarithms pointwise rather than set-wise

The bottom line is that when dealing with complex powers (or even real powers of negative numbers) it is wise to express everything in terms of the standard exponential function defined by the Taylor series above and forget about the meaning of powers in the real case since that can lead one into error; when taking logarithms everything should be thought in terms of sets rather than pointwise, unless you have well defined analytic functions on both sides, so for example defining the $\log$ by cutting the negative imaginary axis, so the argument lives in $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2})$, and considering the function $z^2$ there, one can define a consistent logarithm of $z^2$, call it Log, on that domain for which Log${(-1)^2}$ has a defined pointiwse value, Log${1}$ has a defined pointwise value but they are not necessarily the usual ones and equal - one such choice would fix Log$1=0$ and then for any $z_0$ in the domain, take a smooth path $\gamma$ joining $1$ to $z_0$ and define Log$z_0^2 = \int_{\gamma}\frac{2}{z}$ which doesn't depend on the choice of $\gamma$ in the plane minus the negative imaginary axis; but you can start at $-1$, define Log$(-1)^2 = 2\pi i$ and repeat the procedure above, except that now Log$z_0^2 = \int_{\gamma}{\frac{2}{z}} + 2\pi i$ for any path joining $-1$ to $z_0$. Then you will have well defined number Log${z^2}$ for each $z$ in the domain above, satisfying the required $\exp {Log ({z^2})} = z^2$ but not necesarily Log$(-1)^2=$ Log$1$

Comment: Thats difficult to follow, I should speficy everything to be positive. Assuming $a,b >0$ real, $m,n>0$ integer and $z_1,z_2$ complex, is $(4)$ correct? For some $k$ or for every $k$?

Comment: since any comment about that will get too long I will add another answer below